# How do I remain authenticated when accessing an URL directly with `get` in WWW::Mechanize?

Tags: perl, authentication, mechanize

I'm new to [WWW::Mechanize](http://p3rl.org/WWW%3a%3aMechanize) but I know how to login and then how to use the `follow_link` method to access other pages while I'm logged in. But when I want to access a link directly that is not on the page, I lose my authentication.

Quick sample of the problem:

```
my $LoginURL = "http://www.website.com/user/login.jsp?";
my $DirectURL= "/Somefile?param1&param2";
$mech = WWW::Mechanize->new();
$mech->get($LoginURL);
$mech->submit_form( ... ); # fields and stuff, works fine.
$mech->get($DirectURL);    # This part fails and I'm using the direct URL.
```

I understand how to login and I can navigate around with the `follow_link` method, but when I want to access a URL that is not on the page using the `get` method I simply lose my authentication.

What will I have to do in order to remain authenticated when I want to access a direct URL not located on the current page?

Comment: Does it work if you do the same in a browser? Does not the page include some information to the URL (GET)? I am able to log in to a page and then navigate directly to a different page, still being logged in.

Comment: @choroba : It works out to navigate directly when logged in on the page with a browser. But when i'm doing the same thing here i lose my authentication (cookie and session i guess). I simply can't understand why when i can use the follow_link but not the get because follow_link is basically a get command by analyzing in the source code of Mechanize.

Comment: What about replacing & by &amp; in the URL?

Answer (score -1):

Since HTTP is a stateless protocol, each request is independent of the previous one. In versions previous to HTTP 1.1, the default behavior for HTTP transactions is for a client to contact a server, send a request, and receive a response, and then both the client and server disconnect the TCP connection. If the client needs another resource on the server, it has to reestablish another TCP connection, request the resource, and disconnect. If you have successfully authenticated, the target website might "forget" that when you trying to access the next page. Try to see which value is included in the HTTP "Connection" header. It should be "keep-alive" and not "TE, close". If this is the issue try to modify the "Connection" header. You can try something like this:

```
  $mech->add_header(
  "Connection" => "keep-alive",
  "Keep-Alive" => "115");
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score -3):

$mech->get() is an overload of LWP::UserAgent. It expects absolute URLs.

```
my $uri = $mech->uri();           # Get the current URI
my $uri->path_query($DirectURL);  # Replace the path with file path
$mech->get($uri->as_string);      # Returns http://www.website.com/Somefile?param1&param2
```

Comment: `get` works fine on relative URLs, as long as there is a page already on the stack which can provide a base.

Comment: I didn't realized that before.  Everything I write has absolute uris.